# Python get all <tr> in <tdbody> using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get all <**tr>** in `<tdbody>`

`<tr>` change every `x` second , it's **live-data**
How can I get ? it ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68531719/12446721). Is it working for you? If it worked and solve your issue then don't forget to mark this as accepted answer. And if you like my effort then you may upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
table = driver.find_element(By.tag_name("tdbody")
rows = table.find_elements(By.tag_name("tr"))
```

Remember to get the value from the `.text` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.<browser>()
driver.get("<website url>")

tdbody=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('table').find_element_by_tag_name("tdbody")

while True:
    trs=tdbody.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
    for tr in trs:
        print(tr.text)
        # It is just printing text but if you want to save then make list before while loop and append this tr.text by `list.append(tr.text)`
    time.sleep(1)
    #It will pause for a second and scrape again.
```

It is never ending loop, so be careful, you can make some condition and break that loop. By just using `break` keyword